# Asynctask network connection issue

Tags: android, android-asynctask, connection

i have fourone1 activity, it includes asynctask. Activity works well, when network connection available. When network is gone, program goes in settings for network, but program is crashed in background. How can i solve this problem?

```
public class FourOne1 extends BaseActivityTwo {

    public static final String URL = 
            "http://fastestlaps.com/photos/bmw_m5_e60_4ebe96e6dad77.jpg";


    private String[] menutitles;
    private TypedArray menuIcons;

    TextView tv1 ;
    TextView tv2 ;
    TextView tv3 ;
    TextView tv4 ;
    TextView tv5 ;
    TextView tv6 ;

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.four_one_1);


    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Internet Connection Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FourOne1.this.startActivity(new Intent(
                   Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
               //finish();


    } else { 
    new GetXMLTask().execute();
    }






    menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titlesthree); // load titles from strings.xml

    menuIcons = getResources()
                    .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconsthree);//load icons from strings.xml



    set(menutitles, menuIcons);


    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    tv5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    tv6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);

    tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FourOne1One.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FourOne1Two.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

tv3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FourOne1Three.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});


tv4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FourOne1Four.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});


tv5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FourOne1Five.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});


tv6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FourOne1Six.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});


    // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
    // Execute the task
    task.execute(new String[] { URL });


    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }





    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {





        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap map = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                map = downloadImage(url);
            }
            return map;
        }

        // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

        // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
        private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

            try {
                stream = getHttpConnection(url);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                        decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
        private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException {
            InputStream stream = null;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stream;
        }
    }



}
```

Logcat error

```
07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at com.example.test.FourOne1$GetXMLTask.downloadImage(FourOne1.java:225)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at com.example.test.FourOne1$GetXMLTask.doInBackground(FourOne1.java:203)
    07-17 04:54:32.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1367):     at com.example.test.FourOne1$GetXMLTask.doInBackground(FourOne1.java:1)
```

Comment: You have a null pointer in downloadImage.  My guess would be stream is null because you failed to open a connection with no network, but you have the line count to double check.

Comment: You are executing the AsyncTask at the end of onCreate even if the network check returned false.